# How to access struct variables of shaders in cpp code?

Tags: c++, opengl, struct, glsl

I have a struct defined in the shader file:

```
struct data_t{ 
    float value;
    float baz[3];    
}
```

Then I declared a uniform variable in the same shader:

```
uniform data_t data;
```

My question is, how to feed variable with values from cpp code?

I tried solution from [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/320851/Defining-Structs-in-GLSL) and [this](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/uniform-variables/), i.e. access like this:

```
glGetUniformLocation(program, "data.value")
```

It should work, but it doesn't, I got -1 all the time.

I also tried to use UBO, seems like UBO only works when I declare like this:

```
layout (std140) uniform data_t{
   float value;
   float baz[3];
}data;
```

So how exactly should I feed them with values from cpp?

Comment: does this help: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Uniform_management  ?

Comment: @xaxxon Thanks, but I'm sure I didn't put the same name for multiple uniforms, and I did try to use glUniform* to change the value, but before that I need to get the location of that uniform, right? that's what I'm asking, I kept getting -1 for the location.

Comment: You may want to put something soft down on your desk before you continue reading... `" data.value"` <== there's a leading space in there.

Comment: @xaxxon Sorry, that was a typo...

Comment: A -1 from glGetUniformLocation generally means that the uniform was eliminated by the shader optimizer due to being unused.  Make sure that your shader's result depends on that uniform in some way.